# Ajax возвращает целую страницу вместо нужных данных

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, opencart2.0, content-type

Решил создать в opencart быстрый просмотр товара, но залип на ajax.

Сначала я не использовал  `dataType: 'json'` и в ответ получал целую страницу товара не смотря на то что метод контроллера был пуст.

Сейас добавил `dataType: 'json'`    и      `echo json_encode(array('result' => 'yes'));` - возвращает ошибку с содержанием `Ошибка[object Object]`

```
var fast_review={
    "show": function function_name (product_id) {
          jQuery.ajax({
              method:"POST",
              url: "/catalog/controller/extension/module/fast-review/get_product&product_id="+product_id,
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {id: product_id }
              })
          .done(function( msg ) {
              alert( msg);
              $('.modal-fast-review').html(msg).modal().append('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span></span>Зарыть</button>');
          })
          .fail(function( msg ) {
              alert("Ошибка"+msg);
          });
    }
}


<?php 
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller{
      private function get_product(){
             echo json_encode(array('result' => 'yes'));
             $this->load->model('catalog/product');
             $this->getProduct((int)$this->request->get['product_id']);
             //var_dump($heading_title);//$_POST[id] //$this->model_catalog_product->getProduct((int)$this->request->get['product_id']))
             //$this->response->setOutput("das");
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: мм вроде где то тут надо данные которые приходят засунуть в JSON.parse()

Comment: `JSON.parse(msg)` как оговорил товарищ выше